# nvidia driver error while running program

Tags: compilation, cuda, driver, nvidia

I am getting following error while running my program in jetson-tk1 board

```
root@tegra-ubuntu:~# ./a.out 
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_340'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_340': Function not implemented couldn't get the symbol addr
```

I am getting same error while executing `nvidia-smi` command

My system info is given below

```
Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.40 #22 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 11 18:31:28 CST 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have installed nvidia driver as follows

```
root@tegra-ubuntu:~# apt-get install nvidia-340
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-340 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 522 not upgraded.
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guess what happens is, that it tried to load driver is not compatible for Jetson TK1. The Nvidia have a specific driver for the L4T and this driver is loaded on Jetson default.

So you need to remove this package. And may be execute this command

```
"echo "alias nvidia nvhost_vi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf"
```

A more information you can find on these links

[post on devtalk nvidia](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/745791/could-not-insert-nvidia_340-function-not-implemented/)

[another post on devtalk nvidia](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/818189/error-message-when-running-parallelized-face-detection-on-jetson/)

Comment: I have removed using the command `apt-get remove nvidia-340` Now I am getting following error `couldn't get the symbol addr`

Comment: @user_12 did you reboot your system after remove driver?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted the system

Comment: @user_12 Did you recompile your program? And now do you have the same original error?

Comment: @user_12 If I correct you now you have cuda error in your program. So initial problem with driver is resolved. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109666/discussion-between-alexanderkomarov-and-user-12).